# Does Kotlin support partial application?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, partial-application

Since Kotlin supports many concepts from functional programming, I was wondering if there is a way to do partial application of a function in Kotlin as well?

One such example of where partial application can be useful is:

```
// In one class
fun doSomething(cb: (a, b) -> Unit) {
    <some logic here to compute someField>
    doSomethingElse(cb.applyPartially(someField))
}

// In another class
fun doSomethingElse(cb: (b) -> Unit) {
    <some logic here to compute someOtherField>
    cb(someOtherField)
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Out of the box, no. But it isn't too hard to do with a helper function:

```
    fun add(a: Int, b:Int): Int {
        return a + b
    }

    fun <A, B, C> partial2(f: (A, B) -> C, a: A): (B) -> C {
        return { b: B -> f(a, b)}
    }

    val add1 = partial2(::add, 1)

    val result = add1(2) //3
```

So partial2 takes a function of 2 arguments and the first argument and applies it to get a function of 1 argument. You would have to write such helpers for all arities you need.

Alternatively, you can do it with an extension method:

```
fun <A,B,C> Function2<A,B,C>.partial(a: A): (B) -> C {
    return {b -> invoke(a, b)}
}

val abc: (Int) -> Int = (::add).partial(1)
```

Comment: Now all I need is a way to add an extension function to functions.

Comment: Yeah I was able to get to that point. The issue now is that this only works for the functions with 2 arguments. I am now trying to devise a solution for n argument functions.

Comment: I wrote a javascript script to generate these functions up to function with 20 arguments LOL: https://gist.github.com/idunnololz/56ffb520c164bef13766dc0fb551ee0d

Comment: Isn't a lambda, e.g. `doSomethingElse{ cb(someField, it) }`, a much simpler solution to this?  (Disclaimer: I'm not a FP developer…)

Comment: It's not strictly the same, but you can also define it more directly. `val abc = {b:Int -> add(1, b) }`. Becomes specific to each usage, and convention to partially apply first, and type of parameter has to be explicitly defined. Style choice.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very nice and light library to Kotlin: `org.funktionale`. In module `funktionale-currying` you'll find extenstion methods to lambdas: `curried()` and `uncurried()`.

Example:

```
val add = { x: Int, y: Int -> x + y }.curried()
val add3 = add(3)

fun test() {
    println(add3(5)) // prints 8
}
```

Comment: Small update: the project seems to have been migrated to: https://arrow-kt.io

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1

It actually does, but you'll have to use signatures like

```kotlin
(T1) -> (T2) -> R
```

Here's an example of a curried comparator which allows partial application (the `typealias` added for readability, can just as well be [rewritten](https://pl.kotl.in/EHddGWgbm) w/o any):

```kotlin
typealias CurriedComparator<T> = (T) -> (T) -> Int

fun main() {
    val integers = mutableListOf(42, 0, 1, 3, 2)

    val naturalOrder: CurriedComparator<Int> = { left ->
        { right ->
            // JVM only, essentially the same as `left - right`
            Comparator.naturalOrder<Int>().compare(left, right)
        }
    }

    integers.sortWith { left, right ->
        // Note the partial application:
        naturalOrder(left)(right)
    }

    println(integers)
}
```

Having said the above, the `curried` operation for a two-argument function (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415110/1343979)) can be implemented like this:

```kotlin
val <T1, T2, R> ((T1, T2) -> R).curried: (T1) -> (T2) -> R
    get() = { arg0: T1 ->
        { arg1: T2 ->
            this(arg0, arg1)
        }
    }
```

Usage example:

```kotlin
val difference = { a: Int, b: Int -> a - b }.curried(11)(7)
println(difference) // 4
```

## Option 2

You'll have to overload the `invoke()` operator, e. g.:

```kotlin
    val compareInts: (Int, Int) -> Int =
        { left, right ->
            left - right
        }

    operator fun <T1, T2, R> ((T1, T2) -> R).invoke(t1: T1): (T2) -> R =
        { t2 ->
            this(t1, t2)
        }

    // This is the "normal" invocation:
    val a: Int = compareInts(41, 42)
    // This is the partial application using the overloaded `invoke()` operator:
    val b: Int = compareInts(41)(42)

    check(a == b)
```

## Limitations

The capability of partial application comes at a price. Once we follow the above path, we'll immediately lose access to:

- Java interoperability,
- **default parameters**, and, more importantly,
- **recursion** (can still be implemented using the [*Y combinator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator)).

Speaking of the *recursion* w/o the *Y combinator*, it's still possible, but (in the case of a 2-argument function) you'll have to rewrite

```kotlin
val comparator: (String) -> (String) -> Int = { /*...*/ }
```

as

```kotlin
fun comparator(left: String): (String) -> Int { /*...*/ }
```